# Changing the color of a colorbar in certain sections based on a third variable

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I have the following code. I'm trying to have the values of De_below_line show up as a different color on the colorbar. The colorbar itself should have the range from De.min() to De.max(). While I can get the colors to plot differently on the scatterplot, the values don't transfer across to the colorbar easily. I've included a picture of a potential colorbar below of how I would like it to look and hopefully clarify what I'm trying to do. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from matplotlib.ticker import FormatStrFormatter
    from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
    
    xls = pd.ExcelFile('20240109 - CPeT Export - Rev2.xlsx')
    God = pd.ExcelFile('20231213-Vs calculations.xlsx')
    n = len(xls.sheet_names)
    #------Raw data-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
    dfs = pd.read_excel(xls, sheet_name='SCPTU-12-CPT', skiprows=185, skipfooter=0)
    title = dfs.values[0,0]
    qt = dfs.values[:,5]                                        # Cone tip resistance (MPa)
    ov = dfs.values[:,10]                                       # Vertical total stress (kPa)
    Qtn = dfs.values[:,18]                                      # Normalised cone tip resistance with stress component (-)
    De = dfs.values[:,1]                                        # Imports depth values (m)
    Gor = pd.read_excel(God, sheet_name='SCPTU-12-CPT', skiprows=185, skipfooter=0)
    Go = Gor.values[:,8]                                        # Imports the correct small-strain shear modulus (MPa)
    D = Gor.values[:,0]                                         # Imports depth values (m)
    #------Calculations---------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
    ov = ov/1000
    qn = qt-ov                                                  # Calculates qn
    IG = Go/qn                                                  # Calculates normalised rigidty index
    #------Plotting the results-------------------------------------------------------------------------#
    fig = plt.figure()
    
    y = 2280.4*IG**-1.333
    De_below_line = De[Qtn < y]
    
    cmap = ListedColormap(['blue', 'red'])  # Two colors: below the line, above the line
    colors = np.where(Qtn < y, 'blue', 'red')  # De.min() for below the line, De.max() for above the line
    
    ax = fig.gca()
    ax.set_xscale('log')
    ax.set_yscale('log')
    ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%g'))
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%g'))
    plt.xlabel('Normalised Rigidity Index, $I_G$')
    plt.ylabel('Normalised Cone Tip Resistance, Qtn')
    sc = ax.scatter(IG, Qtn, s=60, label=title, c=colors, cmap=cmap)
    plt.plot([1,330],[(330/1)**(1/0.75),1], linewidth=1, color="black",linestyle='-', marker='None')
    
    cbar = plt.colorbar(sc, ticks=[De.min(), De.max()])
    cbar.ax.invert_yaxis()
    
    ax.set_xlim(1, 1000)
    ax.set_ylim(1, 1000)
    plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you don't want a regular colorbar.  With `imshow` you can show a custom property of the `DE` values. The expression `Qtn < y`, where both parts are numpy arrays, gets converted in a new array with `False` and `True` values.  When interpreted as number, this becomes `0` and `1`. Changing the order of the colors in the colormap will map `1` (`True`, so `Qtn < y` to blue) and `0` to red.

`imshow` needs its input as 2D, so the array needs to be reshaped. `aspect='auto'` avoids the default "square pixels". `origin='lower'` lets the image start at the bottom. `extent` sets the `xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax` as the coordinates (the x values aren't important).

The code below creates a figure with two subplots: the scatter plot at the left, and the bar at the right. The code supposes the `DE` array is strictly ordered from low to high.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib. Colors import ListedColormap
import numpy as np

cmap = ListedColormap(['crimson', 'skyblue'])  # Two colors: above the line, below the line

# create some random data for testing
np.random.seed(1123)
IG = np.logspace(0, 3, 20)
Qtn = np.random.uniform(2, 999, 20)
y = 2280.4 * IG ** -1.333
De = np.linspace(0, 100, 20)

fig, (ax, ax_DE) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(8, 6), gridspec_kw={'width_ratios': [10, 1]})

# create the scatter plot IG vs Qtn
ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.set_yscale('log')
ax.scatter(IG, Qtn, s=60, label='IG vs Qtn', c=(Qtn < y), cmap=cmap)
# ax. Plot([1, 330], [(330 / 1) ** (1 / 0.75), 1], linewidth=1, color="black", linestyle='-', marker='None')
ax.plot(IG, y, linestyle='-', color='black', label='y')
ax.set_xlabel('IG')
ax.set_ylabel('Qtn')
ax.set_title('IG vs Qtn')

# create the bar for DE
ax_DE.imshow((Qtn < y).reshape(-1, 1), aspect='auto', cmap=cmap, origin='lower', extent=(0, 1, De.min(), De.max()))
ax_DE.set_xticks([])  # erase x ticks
ax_DE.yaxis.tick_right()  # place y ticks at the right
ax_DE.set_title('Depth')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: mimicking a colorbar with custom data]

Comment: It worked excellent. Thank you very much for your help! I'm sending you good vibes from Australia.